# Composer error - current identity with name *** and identifier *** not registered during ping error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I did the following steps ...

-> Started the BYFN fabric network . https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html

-> Started composer network with trade-network sample BNA - https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

-> Did everything according to the tutorials and it worked . added two sample records from the composer playground

-> Extended the BYFN network with a third org by using the EYFN tutorial - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html

-> Added a CA docker compose file to start a CA server for Org3 as well .

-> I wanted to install the the trade network BNA to the peer admin of org 3 as well . so followed the same set of steps as per https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org for org3 alone .

-> However i didnt do the **composer network start** step . (which i am not sure whether to do or not)

I am stuck at the ping step which gives the error .

```
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier 'c6f418199d9356a01a526f72839b944100be48a99697d879e3af3bb98a7c2adc', has not been registered
Command failed
```

However the **composer identity request** step works and i am able to store certificates for the card properly .

The set of steps worked properly before adding the third org .  Am i missing anything ? 
Help & Suggestions .

Thanks !

Comment: Have you bound the identity you requested to a participant ?

Comment: i havent no . i am not sure of that step . could u tell me . i did all steps as per tutorial for the new org , however i dint do the bind step .
How do do it ?

Comment: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-bind for example, try also searching for the word bind on the composer doc website

Comment: this should be done after which step ? bind

Comment: If you look at the bind command you will see it requires a public certificate and an existing participant to bind it to. So you need to ensure that these are done/available before you perform the bind.

Comment: I got it to work .! Thanks a lot @david_k

Comment: @Skadoosh How were you able to get it working? I'm also facing the same issue. Thanks